# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user' when I try to filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I would like to filter through the restaurants that the request.user has done. following the docs but i keep getting `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument `user` when I try to filter

## forms.py

```
from .models import Restaurant
from .models import  Item
from django import forms


class LocationCreate(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = [
            'restaurant'
            'category',
            'food_name'
        ]
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['restaurant'].queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

## models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_name    = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    restaurant_photo   = models.ImageField(upload_to='roote_image')
    category      = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    timestamp     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    owner          = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Item(models.Model):
    restaurant= models.ForeignKey(Roote, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner      = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.food_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## views.py

```
class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = ['restaurant','category ', 'food_name ']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post:index')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            roote = restaurant.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user)
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(ItemCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ItemCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user 
        return kwargs
```

## detail.html

```
{% block body %}

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <img src="{{ restaurant.restaurant_photo.url }}" style="width: 250px;" >


        <h1>{{ restaurant.restaurant_name }}</h1>

         {% for item in restaurant.item_set.all %}
             {{ item.food_name }}: {{ item.category}}
             <br>

         {% endfor %}
```

The form works without the filter but it brings in every instance of a restaurant that has been made in the web site

full error:

```
return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Comment: Please provide full stack trace

Comment: added as much as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `form_class` attribute to your view

```
class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post:index')
    form_class = LocationCreate  # <- here

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            roote = restaurant.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(ItemCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ItemCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user 
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Just as a side note i also got an error that said i needed to choose either fields or form_class in the views.py. I chose form_class

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset), this is the signature of the `__init__` method for a ModelForm:

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

See that there is no `user`? This is what the error message is telling you.
If you want to get the user, try via `self.request.user` (or something similiar, depending on what middlewares you use).

Hope that helps!

Comment: so to be clear take away user from the initial parameters and try to just use the filter self.request.user alone?